# Python/C API can't import urllib2 library

Tags: c, macos, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I have to parse a HTML url and return a list of url to use a recursive method of parsing. I'm using BeautifulSoup on Mac OS and I have a problem to import `html_parser.py`

html_parser.py :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


def link_list(urlString):
    siteFile = urllib2.urlopen(urlString)
    siteHTML = siteFile.read()
    siteFile.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(siteHTML, "html.parser")
    liste = []
    for links in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(links.get('href'))
        liste.append(links.get('href'))
    return liste
```

pars.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

int main() {
  Py_Initialize();

  /* 1st: Import the module */
    PyRun_SimpleString("from bs4 import BeautifulSoup\n");
    PySys_SetPath(".");
    PyObject* moduleString = PyString_FromString((char*) "html_parser");
    if (!moduleString) {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Error formating python script\n");
    }

    PyObject* module = PyImport_Import(moduleString);
    if (!module) {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Error importing python script\n");
    }

    /* 2nd: Getting reference to the function */
    PyObject* function = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, (char*)"link_list");
    if (!function) {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Pass valid argument to link_list()\n");
    }

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I need to use `PySys_SetPath(".")` to set the Python Path to my working directory. But by doing this it doesn't recognize bs4, so before changing the path I use `PyRun_SimpleString("from bs4 import BeautifulSoup\n")` but when I'm trying to do the same thing for urllib2 (`PyRun_SimpleString("import urllib2\n")`) I got this error :

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 80, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

Someone helped me, but before the name of my Python program was `parser.py`and then when we don't use the SetPath c is using an another file int default Python Path. So Python.h doesn't recognize ether bs4 and urllbi2.

**EDIT :**

I just checked the version of my system with `PyRun_SimpleString("print(sys.version)")` and got this :

```
2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 19:40:32)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)]
```

So I'm on Python 2.7.10 and not Python 3, I don't have to use url.request module...

Comment: Your system Python shouldn't have anything to do with this: you're using Homebrew installed Python, which is version 2.7.13. That means that if you're compilation flags are set incorrectly, you may pick up the wrong `Python.h` include file (and link with the wrong Python library). Do check the compilation output (make sure it's verbose enough) and options when compiling `pars.c`.

Comment: I'm not using the homebrew python for it, well I think. Here' my compilation `gcc -I/usr/include/python2.7 pars.c -lpython2.7 -o pars -Wall` I found it in all tutorial I found and I don't know how I can check my compilation output.

Comment: Your error messages includes paths starting with `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13`; that clearly indicates Homebrew. Your script also starts with `#! /usr/local/bin/python2.7`, which is not the default system Python (and very likely the one installed by Homebrew). If you want to simply use the system Python, perhaps changing that first line in your script to point to the appropriate Python executable may solve your problem.